# To process csv data set in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, jupyter, tagging

I am worried to process data set developed in Sindhi language. I followed all steps but unable to process the data set. May any one help me in loading and importing csv file from local drive. 
I tried like:

```
import csv
data C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv
```

got response like:

```
File "<ipython-input-71-6a0a9456deeb>", line 1
    data C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

then enter query as:

```
import csv
with open(C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv, 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

and got response as:

```
File "<ipython-input-74-29f185d274e2>", line 2
    with open(C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv, 'rb') as f:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

than process as:

```
from sklearn import datasets
sindhi2 = datasets.load_sindhi2()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
```

and got response as:

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-119477fe5453> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn import datasets
----> 2 sindhi2 = datasets.load_sindhi2()
      3 digits = datasets.load_digits()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'load_sindhi2'
```

Please help me in loading and importing dataset from my local drive D and process POS tagging and feature deriving  in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Your second block is almost correct, all you need is to quote the file name:

```
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Also note that I used raw string (see the `r` before the single quote) so that I don't have to escape the backspaces.

## Update

Since you are using Python 3, you should use mode `'r'`:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv', 'r') as f:
```

Or omit the mode:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv') as f:
```

I have tried this with Anaconda + Python 3 Jupyter notebook.

Comment: thank you for answer. It is working well but one error comes which generate barrier to process the query. Following is the error. Please help me removing this error.

Comment: This is error. How I should adjust this error.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: I'm using Python 2 and mode `'rb'` seems to make sense. If you are using Python 3, change the mode to `'r'` to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you dear for response and help. I processed query with r but same error response received. i am using anaconda3. following error acquired:  Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-76531ab74d48> in <module>()
      1 import csv
      2 with open(r'C:\Users\mazhar\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sindhi2.csv', 'rb') as f:
----> 3     data = list(csv.reader(f))

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Please see my update. Please note that in your message, you were still using mode `rb`